# Distinguishing Tuple and Multi-Argument Functions

Tags: swift

I write this function in playground which has *value* parameter of tuple type and return type is tuple.

```
func tuple(value: (Int, Int) ) -> (first: Int, second: Int) {
    let firstGrabTuple = value.0 + 5
    let secondGrabTuple = value.1 + 5
    return (firstGrabTuple, secondGrabTuple)
}
```

Then I assigned it to constant called `closure`

```
let closure = tuple
//(Playground showing) let closure became a function of type (Int, Int) -> (first: Int, second: Int)
```

Then for double check I write another function that takes closure as its parameter, of type `((Int, Int)) -> (Int, Int)`

```
func anotherTuple(_ closure: ((Int, Int)) -> (Int, Int)) {
    closure((5, 5))
}
```

when I call `anotherTuple`

```
anotherTuple { (x) -> (Int, Int) in
    let first = x.0 + 5
    let second = x.1 + 5
    return (first, second)
}
//prints .0 10, .1 10 as expected
```

So My question is as mention above when first function `tuple` I assigned it to constant called `closure` became of type `(Int, Int) -> (first: Int, second: Int)`. But in second function If i have to use a parameter of type as tuple I have to set its parameter in double parentheses like `(_ closure: ((Int, Int)) -> (Int, Int))`.

[image]
But If I remove those double parentheses from `anotherTuple` function parameter then it will only expect 2 values as multi-argument function. No error for used as multi-argument function instead of tuple argument why is that? Added image for more detail.
and second question is why that

```
let closure = tuple
  //let closure became a function of type (Int, Int) -> (first: Int, second: Int)
```

not became of type `((Int, Int)) -> (first: Int, second: Int)`

**Note - When I tried to pass that constant named `closure` as argument to another function which will expect closure of type `((Int, Int)) -> (Int, Int)` then while typing `closure` showing me it as `((Int, Int)) -> (Int, Int)` in auto complete code.

Comment: You are out of your track maybe. Your _anotherTuple_ function takes in a parameter of type `((Int, Int)) -> Int` not `((Int, Int)) -> (Int, Int)`. How do you expect you could pass in the `closure` constant?

Comment: I know that function is different. I don't wanted to edit again this long explanation. I tried to pass it on another function which takes in  a parameter of type `((Int, Int)) -> (Int, Int)`. So I tried then add that note. In that note I clearly said another function and not `anotherTuple` from my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct about the confusion. I'm somewhat going to just restate your understanding, and say "yes, tuples in Swift are weird and slightly broken."

Swift does not distinguish between functions that take tuples vs multiple arguments in some ways, but does distinguish in other ways. (This is one of many reasons to avoid tuples at this point in Swift's life.)

First, these two functions have *almost* the same type in Swift (note that `Void` and `()` are identical):

```
func tuple(value: (Int, Int) ) {}      // (Int, Int) -> Void
func two(value1: Int, value2: Int) {}  // (Int, Int) -> Void
```

They look the same. But if you define a function that accepts that type, it can't take `tuple`:

```
func take(f: (Int, Int) -> Void) {}
take(f: tuple)  // Fails
take(f: two)    // ok
```

But if you define a function that takes `((Int, Int)) -> Void` it can accept either function:

```
func take(f: ((Int, Int)) -> Void) {}
take(f: tuple)  // ok
take(f: two)    // ok
```

That suggests that `(Int, Int) -> Void` is a subtype of `((Int, Int)) -> Void`.

But variables belie this:

```
var f: (Int, Int) -> Void
f = tuple   // Ok
f = two     // Ok

var g: ((Int, Int)) -> Void
g = tuple   // ok
g = two     // ok

g = f  // ok
f = g  // ok
```

And that suggests that `(Int, Int) -> Void` and `((Int, Int)) -> Void` are the same type. But the `take` function indicates they're not.

Yes. All of that is true at the same time. Functions that accept tuples are not a coherent type in Swift (they do not occupy a clearly-deliniated spot in the type hierarchy). That's just where we are in Swift today.

---

Old, incorrect answer.

<strike>This is just a quirk of Playgrounds, and you should feel free to open a [radar](https://bugreport.apple.com) about that.</strike>

If you check `type(of: closure)`, it'll print the type you expect. Swift knows the correct type; Playgrounds just displays the wrong thing.

Comment: Oh so It is a mistake of playground. Ok I just started learning and of course I will check type(of: closure). Also there is one thing If i call anotherTuple dunction with 2 values it became multi argument not anymore tuple type even I mentioned parameter type with double parentheses. If type of closure expect tuple type then there is no strictness of xcode. It allows me to put (x, y) insted of x. But if I remove those double parentheses then it give me error for using just (x) and tell me expecting one more value.

Comment: I guess xcode wants me to more explicit when using tuples but not with multiple arguments. and `type(of: closure)` still showing me same result but in auto complete code I am getting right result.

Comment: In Playgrounds, if I enter `type(of: closure)`, I see `((Int, Int) -> (first: Int, second: Int)).Type`. Isn't that what you expected?

Comment: Note that tuples are a somewhat messy feature in Swift and have been modified several times (and are very likely to be modified several more times). In general, they should be avoided in Swift unless they are extremely localized in use (I occasionally use them for internal functions that are called only from one place). Otherwise, you generally want a struct. In some languages, tuples are very powerful and an important part of the language, but that's not true in Swift today.

Comment: Ok sir. I am new to programming and swift is my first language. yeah documentation also says they should be avoided. And about `type(of: closure)` I was expecting `( ((Int, Int)) -> (first: Int, second: Int))` double parentheses around parameter. Because when I create function which takes a closure of tuple type then It should be `((Int, Int))`  I have edited my question and add Image too. can you please check that too?

Comment: Because there is only one thing can differentiate to tuple and multi-argument closure is that double parentheses. `func tuple(value: ((Int, Int)) -> (Int, Int) )`  and `func multiArgument(value: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) )`

Comment: That is a perfect example of a problem and very well explained. Is is better to avoid tuple right now. I was completing closure topic and they can take tuple as parameter type and return type. So i was curious about type of multi argument function vs tuple type function. Finally feeling relax with the help of good illustration.